# Is it possible to pass an argument as a variable to set up a type in an Angular method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a service with a *saveEntity* method. I want to use it into other services (receptive services lets say) because these receptive services has all a similar save... method that I want to exchange for my saveEntity. Each receptive service (in this case company.service) has its own type for the data retrieve by the observable **Observable**:

```
saveCompany(company) {
this.store.setLoading(true);
let subscription: Observable<Company>;
if(company.id === 0 || company.id === undefined || company.id === null) {
  delete(company.id);
  subscription = this.http.post<Company>(`${environment.apiRootUrl}/Companies`, company);
} else {
  subscription = this.http.put<Company>(`${environment.apiRootUrl}/Companies/${company.id}`, company);
}

subscription.subscribe(() => {
  this.store.update((state) => { return { ...state, saved: true }});
  this.notificationService.success$(this.translateService.instant('common.messages.saved'));
  this.store.setLoading(false);
}, error => {
  if (error.status === 409) {
    const message = error.error.Code === 69 ? this.translateService.instant('common.errors.maxUsers') : error.error.Message;
    this.notificationService.error$(message);
  }
  this.store.setLoading(false);
});
```

}

How could I include the type as an argument into the saveEntity method?

Comment: Do you know there's a `Subscription` type? You are calling an Observable "subscription", but it's not a Subscription, it's an Observable, that's such a strange naming

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
saveCompany<T>(company: T) {
   ...
   let subscription: Observable<T>;
   ...
   return this.http.post<T>(API);
}
```